# JAVA_HOME Issue occurs while installing Android studio

Tags: android, jvm

I have tried to install the Android Studio 64-bit operating system(windows 7 ultimate)in my machine and set the JAVA_HOME as C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21; in the environment variable but it's reports the following error:
The environment variable JAVA_HOME(with the value of C:\programFiles\Java\jdk1.7.0_21;)does not point to a valid JVM installation.

How can i resolve that one.

Comment: does that folder contain the valid installation of java?

Comment: Yes, it is properly installed.

Answer (score 0):

First try to run java from the directory you are using as default installation.
There could be some problems with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Update your Java Version to 1.8.x......

Be sure that your JDK is **64 Bit**.

Point your JAVA_HOME variable to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_xx\ where "xx" is the update version number.

And be sure to put JAVA_HOME in **System Variables** rather than User Variables